# How do I sort a list of users by name on a node server?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express

I have created several user accounts on mongodb and i want to sort them out by user name. I compare the user names in the database against a string provided through aaxios request with a body value that is taken from an input value, like this:

**frontend**

```
const findUsers = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await axios.post(`http://localhost:8080/search-users/${_id}`, { searchValue }); 
                setReturnedUser(response.data.matchedUser);
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        }

        findUsers();
```

**backend**

```
exports.sort = (req, res) => {
    let result;

    User.find({ name: req.body.searchValue }).exec((error, users) => {
        if (error) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                message: error,
            });
        }

        result = users;

        res.status(200).json({
            message: 'Description added successfully',
            matchedUser: result,
        });
    });
};
```

The problem with this approach is that the users are returned only after I type in the entire name.
What I want is that the users to get returned as I type in the name, so several matching users will het returned when I start typing and as I continue the list will narrow down, until only the matching user remains.

I have successfully achieved this on the react side, but that was possible only by fetching all the users from the database, which would be a very bad idea with a lot of users. The obvious solution is to do the sorting on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filtering on the client-side is possible but with some tweaks to your architecture:

1. Create an end-point in node that returns all the users as JSON.  Add caching onto this end-point.  A call to origin would only occur very infrequently.  YOu can then filter the list easily.
2. Use something like GraphQL and Appollo within node.  This will help performance

To do the filtering in node you can use a normal array.filter()

I woul do the filter in mongo as the quick approach and then change it if you notice performance issues.  It is better no to do pre-optimisation. As Mongo is NoSQL it wshould be quick

Comment: Thanks, the filter method worked. I was focused so much on other ways of doing it that I forgot about the simplest ones.